# Implement the domready plugin with requirejs and other dependancies

Tags: javascript, requirejs

My current require line looks like this

```
  require(['requireconfig', 'Utility',  'validation/Validator', 'calculation/Calculator', 'format/Formator'], function (requireconfig, Utility, Validator, Calculator, Formator ){
```

When I attempt to require the DomReady plugin I get an error that one of my functions is not available in the Utility dependancy... It seems to be running the code within my fucntion prior to all the dependancies loading.

This is my attempt

```
  require(['requireconfig', 'DomReady!', 'Utility',  'validation/Validator', 'calculation/Calculator', 'format/Formator'], function (requireconfig, Utility, Validator, Calculator, Formator ){
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out!
I had forgot to complete the function arguments.

Sorry!